# Каким образом можно получить одинаковые(названия) файлы из папок? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть фунция os.walk, получаю кортеж их папок и их файлов.Как мне записать в список лишь одинаковые названия файлов и их путь? Например есть каталог А в нем подкаталоги В С. Каталог В имеет два файла 1.txt, 2.txt. Каталог С имеет файл 1.txt.

Comment: Используйте коллекцию `Counter`, например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дерево:

```
A
├── B
│   ├── 1.txt
│   └── 2.txt
└── C
    └── 1.txt
```

Находим дубликаты:

```
In [16]: import os

In [17]: duplicate_files = {}

In [18]: for dirname, dirs, filenames in os.walk("A"):
    ...:     for filename in filenames:
    ...:         duplicate_files.setdefault(filename, []).append(dirname)
    ...:

In [19]: duplicate_files = {k: v for k, v in duplicate_files.items() if len(v) > 1}

In [20]: duplicate_files
Out[20]: {'1.txt': ['A/C', 'A/B']}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Для Python 3.x — можно и стоит использовать `pathlib`. В примере ниже — результат представлен в виде объекта класса pathlib.Path, что позволяет использовать соответствующие аттрибуты для операций с путем (open, read_text, read_bytes, stat, unlink, rename).

```py
import pathlib
import operator as op


def find_dubs(
        pattern='**',               # все файлы в т.ч. и в подкаталогах
        workdir=pathlib.Path.cwd()  # текущая рабочая папка
):
    dups = dict()

    # приводим к pathlib.Path, если передали иное (str, os.path)
    workdir = pathlib.Path(workdir)

    assert workdir.is_dir(), 'Путь должен быть существующей папкой'

    for pth in workdir.glob(pattern):
        # создаем список дубликатов, если он не существует
        dups.setdefault(pth.name, list()).append(pth)
    
    # Далее ФП — обращайте внимание на порядок действий
    dups = dict(  # 3. Преобразовываем последовательность в dict
        filter(
            lambda x: len(x[1]) > 1,  # 2. Отбрасываем все списки с длинной 1 и меньше
            dups.items(),             # 1. Получаем последовательность key-value
        )
    )
    return dups
```